# why getting socket closed error after running script by jmeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

I am getting "Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection reset" this type of error after running jmeter script

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please post the code that generates the error, so you can get some help

Answer (score 3):

I bet that you're experiencing the problem described in [Connection Reset since JMeter 2.10 ?](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed) wiki page

So I would recommend to take the next steps:

1. Switch "Implementation" of all your HTTP Request Samplers to "HttpClient4". The best way to do this is using [HTTP Request Defaults](http://blazemeter.com/blog/http-request-defaults) so you will have to change the value in just one place.
2. As per the wiki page add the next 2 lines to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   httpclient4.retrycount=1
   hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
   ```
3. Add the next line to *hc.parameters* file (same location, /lib folder)

   ```
   http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
   ```
4. Remember to restart JMeter after making these changes, properties change is not dynamic, they're being picked up upon JMeter startup.

Hope this helps.